# using same fixed background for multiple elements and browser performance

Tags: html, css, browser

I am using same high resolution background as a fixed body background and i use it with five more elements as well

```
body{
  background: url(highres.png) top center;
  background-attactment: fixed;
} 

box1{
  background: url(highres.png) top center;
  background-attactment: fixed;
}
box2{
  background: url(highres.png) top center;
  background-attactment: fixed;
}
.......
.......
```

My question is, If i use url(image.png) several times as above, does the browser load it once or each url at a time? Will this be a reason for a slow browsing experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that way it reads it three times : you could do this

```
body, #box1, #box2{
  background: url(highres.png) top center;
  background-attactment: fixed;
}
```

and next it you can style them like you would do normally